# What is the expected distance between endpoints of $n$ line segments of length 1 connected at random angles?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, random-walk, multiple-integral, geometric-probability

Start at the origin and take n line segments and connect them end to end each at random angles. What is the expected distance of the endpoint from the origin of the resulting path?

Clearly when $n=1$ the expected distance is $1$. When $n=2$ we can find the expected distance by integrating

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int^{2\pi}_0 2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2} \right) dx = \frac{4}{\pi}$$

For $n=3$, it is easy to simulate and find the distance is approximately $1.58$. For $n=4$ the simulated distance is $1.82$ and for $n=5$ we get approximately $2.02$.

Can one find a general formula for any $n$?

Comment: How are the $n$ segments connected? End to end? Do their centers coincide? Some other method?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer End to end. Thanks, I added this for clarity.

Comment: How is this different from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RandomWalk2-Dimensional.html ?  Is this not a 2 dimensional random walk?

Comment: @GingerBreadMan It seems to describe the same question but why does the answer $\sqrt{n}$ not match up with $n=2$ and the other simulations?

Comment: @Goldbug: $\sqrt n$ is the root mean square distance, which is straightforward to compute, not the average distance, which you're asking for. (The root mean square distance is the square root of the average of the squared distance.) Your problem seems to lead to an elliptic integral already for $n=3$, so I have little hope that you'll find a closed form (let alone for general $n$).

Comment: For the $n = 2$ case, you should get for the expectation of $d$:

$(1/(2 \pi))\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{2(1-\cos(\theta))}$

where $\theta$ is the angle between the first and second unit vectors.

Comment: @GingerBreadMan: That's precisely what's written in the question, just with $\sqrt{2(1-\cos\theta)}$ simplified to $2\sin\left(\frac x2\right)$.

Comment: Then all is well.

Comment: For setting it up, the problem is solving the integral $$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^n}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} ...\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \cos \theta_k\right)^2+\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin \theta_k\right)^2} d\theta_1 d\theta_2...d\theta_n$$

Comment: The integrand in my previous comment can be rewritten as $\sqrt{n + 2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sum_{m=k+1}^{n} \cos(\theta_k-\theta_m)}$

Comment: I suggest you approach it recursively. If the expected distance for $n$ segments is $d_n$, how is $d_{n+1}$ related to $d_n$?

Comment: @joriki Yes, I found the n=3 case difficult to simplify down so I thought this problem might be beyond a closed form.

Comment: Maybe finding the joint distribution between the final angle and length given the distribution for the previous angle and length would be easier. I'm not great with probability, so I don't know how to handle this approach.

Comment: Asymptotically, it is $\frac{\sqrt{n\pi}}{2}$ using the asymptotic distance distribution from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.2995.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Let each line segment be a unit vector

$$ < cos(\theta) , sin(\theta) > $$

Adding up n unit vectors gives the resultant vector from the beginning to the end of the string

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n < cos(\theta_k) , sin(\theta_k) > $$

The magnitude of the resultant vector is the distance from beginning to end

$$ D = |< \sum_{k=1}^n cos(\theta_k) , \sum_{k=1}^n sin(\theta_k) >| $$

That equals

$$ \sqrt{(\sum_{k=1}^n cos(\theta_k))^2 + (\sum_{k=1}^n sin(\theta_k))^2} $$

To find the average distance, we need to add up the distances from every possible combination of thetas and divide by the number of combinations. Since each theta can be any value between 0 and 2 pi, we use an integral

$$ \frac{1}{(2\pi)^n} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \dots \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{(\sum_{k=1}^n cos(\theta_k))^2 + (\sum_{k=1}^n sin(\theta_k))^2} d\theta_1 \dots d\theta_n $$

Solve that and you get your average distance for any n